# Messenger Chatbot OTN Error : (#100) One time token provided is not valid

Tags: chatbot, messenger

I am trying to create a chatbot through messenger and have decided to use OTN ( one time notification). I have followed the doc provided by Facebook - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/one-time-notification . However, I am receiving this error message - **(#100) One time token provided is not valid.**

This is the response upon clicking the notify button :

optin:

```
{
   type: 'one_time_notif_req',
   payload: 'notifyUser',
   one_time_notif_token: '3206373991177755392'
}
```

This is the message I am trying to send back using the otn token :

```
{
   "recipient": 
   {
       "one_time_notif_token":"3206373991177755392"
   },
   "message": {
       "text":"hi"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here is error response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWt0i.png)facing the same issue, I think its a bug because 7-8 days ago we were not getting the OTN token postback and now unable to send  OTN. Asked facebook but they said OTN is on beta so no support available.

also tried via graph api explorer and changing the page token, change token to number type but same result.